# Wordpress Website Frontend Google Translate Automatically

Tags: wordpress, multilingual

I have wordpress site in English, i want to translate whole site to swedish using Google translate automatically when site is loading,

but i don't want to show any language selector on font end.and also don't want to show the google translate bar.

i search around 2days but can't got a answers.

is there any wordpress plugin for do this kind of magic.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get code for specific language from here https://translate.google.com/manager/add
and select only "Swedish" add code to your site. Using javascript or jquery select the langague from select box after loading page and make the select box display:none;

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#google_languaes").val(1);
       $("#google_languaes").css({display: "none"});
   })
```

Comment: when i use $("#google_languaes").val('sv');
 it didn't fire the translate event on site :)

Comment: i dodn't think #google_languaes this is the id of that element first get the id of element

Comment: ya but didn't fire that translate event. i tried lot using firebug